# How to assign dame class selector but different array using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom

I am trying to translate part of the code from JavaScript to jQuery equivalent for testing. Part of the JavaScript looks like:

```
var cbtn = document.getElementsbyClassName("calcbutton");
console.log(cbtn);

for(var i=0; i < cbtn.length; i++) {
cbtn[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
     console.log("clicked");
  });
}
```

I translated into this jQuery equivalent:

```
$(function() {
    var cbtn = $(".calcbutton");
    console.log(cbtn);

    for(var i=0; i < cbtn.length; i++) {

        cbtn[i].click( function(){
            console.log("Clicked!");
        });
    }
});
```

All class the selector calcbutton have the same name. I'm trying to make each individual calcbutton unique with array assigned as in calcbutton[0], calcbutton[1], ... explicitly where the actual array serve as unique identifier. Looks like the jQuery version isn't working. Need help on this one.

Answer (score 0):

`cbtn` is a jQuery object, and doing `[n]` on that collection you're retrieving it's JS DOM Element representation,
in order to use jQuery methods on that Element, like `.click()` etc, you need to  reassign it to jQuery therefore wrapping it back again into a jQuery object.

Also, don't make functions within a for loop, move a function outside - and only instantiate it inside the loop, passing the current iteration `i` as argument. (Or eventually use closures):

```js
$(function() {
  var cbtn = $(".calcbutton");
  
  // Don't make functions within for loops!
  // Instead define it outside and pass arguments (`i` in this case)
  function doSomething(i) {
    $(cbtn[i]).click(function() {
      console.log("Clicked index: "+ i);
    });
  }
  
  for (var i = 0; i < cbtn.length; i++) {
    doSomething(i); // ...instead
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="calcbutton">1</button>
<button class="calcbutton">2</button>
```

so your issue is that within your `for` loop you're reassigning `i` times a click handler over the same collection of elements. Since it's a loop, at the time of exiting the `[i]` will always refer to the last index.

#### example using *anonymous closure* function:

```js
$(function() {
  var cbtn = $(".calcbutton");

  for (var i = 0; i < cbtn.length; i++) {
    (function(i) { // Closure
      $(cbtn[i]).click(function() {
        console.log("Clicked index: " + i);
      });
    }(i)); // Instantiate and pass argument
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="calcbutton">1</button>
<button class="calcbutton">2</button>
```

**Use jQuery** instead:

I cannot see any reason to do so since using jQuery you can simply do:

```
$(function() {

  var cbtn = $(".calcbutton");
  // console.log(cbtn);

  cbtn.click(function(){
    console.log("Clicked!"+ cbtn.index(this)); // to get the index of the clicked one
    // console.log( this );    // DOM Element
    // console.log( $(this) ); // jQuery object (Element)
  });

});
```

where the `click` method is assigned (internally already using a for loop) to every `.calcbutton` element. To retrieve the actually clicked one refer to it using the `this` keyword (see example above) or using `$(this)` → if you need to work on that element using jQuery.

Comment: I could be wrong but I think `console.log("Clicked!"+ i);` is always going to print the same value (the length of the array)

Comment: @leo.fcx fixed. Thx

Comment: I was thinking on using `$.index` as follows: `cbtn.index(e.target)` ... just an idea :)